# Angular-2 nested routing for two level

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a route config as follow

```typescript
export const ProductRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'product/:api_key',
    component: ProductComponent,
    children:[
        { 
            path: 'productType', component: productTypesComponent,
      //        children:[
            //      { path: 'productEntry', component: productEntriesComponent }
            // ]
      },
    ],
    canActivate: [CanActivateService]
  }
];
```

It works for one level of child route but when I add second level child `productEntry` it stops working even though my router config show correct order of child.

Any useful resource will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: any error you are getting ?

Comment: Please make sure that you had added router-outlet tag on second level child (productTypesComponent).

Comment: I'm getting Error: Cannot match any routes: 'product/blt1b502f126e0ddf02/productType'..

Its works if I comment the 2nd level child of productEntry

Comment: @ Ravinder Kumar  yes I have added...

Comment: @HarshPatel, Here URL parameter creating problem. I'll suggest you to instead passing value through URL parameter, use shared services. Then you routing will work properly.

Comment: @RavinderKumar I don't think so....

Comment: @HarshPatel, it is so. When application generating URL for your 'ProdcutType' page it generating 'product/blt1b502f126e0ddf02/productType' URL. When routing engine looks for routing configuration in respect to generated URL, it doesn't find any component registered.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add an empty path:

```
children:[
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'productEntry' }
    { path: 'productEntry', component: productEntriesComponent }
]
```